# Support RST markup in lektor?

Tags: markdown, markup, restructuredtext, lektor

I have checked the CMS. The programme looks very nice.

Instead of markdown I would like to use rather restructured text.

Is RST markup also supported?

Answer (score 2):

RST is not currently supported, but it would be easy enough to add with a plugin. For example, I have a plugin that supports an alternate dialect of Markdown:

[lektor_blog_posts.py](https://github.com/ajdavis/emptysquare-lektor/blob/master/emptysquare/packages/blog-posts/)

For more information on plugin development, see [Spencer Nelson's Writing a Lektor publisher plugin](http://spenczar.com/posts/2015/Dec/24/lektor-publisher-plugin/) and the [Lektor plugin guide](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/plugins/dev/)

Comment: This is all true, however there is a plugin that someone made already that you can use if you don't want to make one yourself. https://github.com/fschulze/lektor-rst. At this time it's not yet added to Lektor's plugin list and it's unofficial, but it may help you out.